# PHP image display

Tags: php, html, css, image

I made this code to display an image. The link to the image is in the database and the image is stored in a folder called uploads in the root. I am getting a broken image displayed back but no error. Any help would be much appreciated. thanks

```
$sql= "SELECT image FROM images";
$res= mysql_query($sql);
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($res))
{
echo("<td><img src=/uploads/". $row['image'] ." width = 100</td><br>");
}
```

Comment: You might want to validate your HTML (see: http://validator.w3.org/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change that echo line to this...

```
echo("<td><img src='/uploads/". $row['image'] ."' width=100 ></td>");
```

You were missing single quotes, and closing >

Also you shouldn't have a  < br > after a < / td >, it would usually just be another < td > after

Ive taken it out

**EDIT**

You were echoing uploads folder twice...once in the img and once from the database.
This should work, using only the database value...since you stored with the 'uploads/' folder already attached.

```
 echo("<td><img src='". $row['image'] ."' width=100 ></td>");
```

Comment: width=100px ? in HTML ? without quotes ? maybe it'll work, but that's not good syntax...

Comment: still doesn't show the image. any other suggestions.

Comment: what does the complete source say for the <img> link? when you view source

Comment: the complete source seems right it says but it is repeating the destination folder twice.
<td><img src='/uploads/uploads/backing.png' width = 100></td><br><td><img src='/uploads/uploads/advert2.jpg' width = 100></td><br></div>

Comment: I thought it was just the uploads folder....not uploads/uploads/

Comment: yeah i dont know why its repeating upload twice. the link in the database is uploads/image.png

Comment: then my new code above should do the trick :)

Comment: thanks KyleK that works perfectly now. if you dont mind me bothering you.... how come i dont need to specify the uploads folder?

Comment: you have that stored in your database already.

Comment: Because the database value already had the uploads/ folder attached , so if you go to your database and actually look at the entries in 'image' it will have uploads attached to it

Comment: alright i get it now. thanks a million